# Azure Service Bus Queue: Messages are not being sent

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm sending messages to a Service Bus Queue from a Worker Role. I noticed that randomly some messages are lost.

When I debug, I set a breakpoint after the Send method and log into my Azure Panel to check if the message queue increased. What I found out is that strangely, messages are not added to the queue some times. But it is not randomly. The pattern is: One message is added correctly and the next is lost, then again next is ok, and the next is lost.

I've implemented a retry pattern like the following but apparently not all the messages are sent correctly.

My code is:

```cs
var baseAddress = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("namespaceAddress");
var issuerName = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("issuerName");
var issuerKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("issuerKey");
var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
Uri namespaceAddress = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", baseAddress, string.Empty);

this.namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(namespaceAddress, TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerKey));
this.messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(namespaceAddress, TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(issuerName, issuerKey));
//namespaceManager.GetQueue("chatmessage");
QueueClient client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("chatmessage");
APPService.Model.MessageReceived messageReceived = new Model.MessageReceived();
messageReceived.From= e.From;
messageReceived.Op = e.Operator;
messageReceived.Message = e.Body;
BrokeredMessage msg = null;

// Use a retry policy to execute the Send action in an asynchronous and reliable fashion.
retryPolicy.ExecuteAction
(
    (cb) =>
    {
        // A new BrokeredMessage instance must be created each time we send it. Reusing the original BrokeredMessage instance may not 
        // work as the state of its BodyStream cannot be guaranteed to be readable from the beginning.
        msg = new BrokeredMessage(messageReceived);

        // Send the event asynchronously.
        client.BeginSend(msg, cb, null);
    },
    (ar) =>
    {
        try
        {
            // Complete the asynchronous operation. This may throw an exception that will be handled internally by the retry policy.
            client.EndSend(ar);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure that any resources allocated by a BrokeredMessage instance are released.
            if (msg != null)
            {
                msg.Dispose();
                msg = null;
            }
        }
    },
    ()=>{},
    (ex) =>
    {
        // Always dispose the BrokeredMessage instance even if the send operation has completed unsuccessfully.
        if (msg != null)
        {
            msg.Dispose();
            msg = null;
        }

        // Always log exceptions.
        Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
    }
);
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I've been finding that messages don't send if I Dispose them after ```await qc.SendAsync```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your code I am unable to notice anything that cloud lead up to the issue.
I suppose the counter on the portal is not updated in real time so I would not consider it as a test result.

I know I am not helping right now, but If I had the doubt you are expressing, I would build a end-to-end test to send and receive the messages, comparing the messageId.

Do you already use [Service Bus Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh532261%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) by Paolo Salvatori on MSDN? You can use it to test the entities. It is a reliable tool to explore and test Service Bus.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check the Service Bus Explorer.